# How to build your Python app distribution on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, setup.py

I am trying to build a distribution using Python's console on a Windows computer.

I am working through the "Head First Python" book, and I'm currently stuck on page 41 (Build your Distribution).

The book states

> **The distribution utilities include all of the smarts required to build a distribution.** Open a terminal window within your "nester" folder and type a single command:
>
> ```
> python3 setup.py sdist
> ```
>
> If you are using Windows, replace "python3" in these commands with "C:\Python31\python.exe"

First, I don't know how to open a console from within a folder, so I just opened Python's console from the application's list.

Second, when the console is open it displays "C:\Python31\python.exe" so I believe it's the current working directory.

My module's folder is installed in the default folder for Python "Python31" and setup.py is both in the "nester" folder and up a directory.

The inputs I have put in the console so far:

```
"C:\Python31\python.exe setup.py sdist"
"setup.py sdist"
"C:\Python31\python.exe setup.py bdist"
"setup.py bdist"
```

I'm not sure what else I am missing to "Build a Distribution", the book doesn't use "Py to Exe" and I would like to stay away from 3rd party applications. A few blogs also suggested staying away from it.

Comment: They are asking for a normal console, not the Python console. Go to the start menu, choose Run and type `cmd`. If you are on Windows 8/10 and there is no Run, just type `cmd` and choose Command Prompt.

Comment: You shouldn't put your module's folder in the Python31 directory, put is someplace else like `C:\myproject`. If you only have Python 3 installed you should be able to just type `python setup sdist` and the Windows command-line (cmd.exe) prompt. However you must first set the current working directory by typing `cd c:\myproject` folder (if that's were you put it). The `setup.py` file should also be placed there.

Comment: To build python, forget the ancient and obsolete book and read the relevant sections of the Devguide `https://docs.python.org/devguide/` starts with the basic steps, but assumes you have the required hg and compiler.  `https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows` says more about the free MS compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the command prompt by Windows+r and type "CMD"
2. Change the directory to the Nester folder path by

   ```
   cd desktop\Nester
   ```

   - Assuming folder is created on desktop
3. Now execute the command

   ```
   c:\python32\python.exe setup.py sdist
   ```

   - Write the path to the python exe file